# Trying to get list of friends from twitter using httparty(ruby)

Tags: ruby, twitter, httparty

I am trying to get the list of specific user`s friends from twitter.
This is my code -

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class TwitterData
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'http://api.twitter.com/1/'
  default_params :output => 'json'
  format :json

  def self.get_username_data(username)
    get('statuses/friends.json' , :query => { :screen_name => username })
  end
end

puts "Please your twitter username - "
twitter_username = gets
puts TwitterData.get_username_data(twitter_username).inspect
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
Please your twitter username -
twitter
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crack-0.1.8/lib/crack/json.rb:14:in `rescue in parse': Invalid JSON string (Crack::ParseError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crack-0.1.8/lib/crack/json.rb:12:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:116:in `json'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:136:in `parse_supported_format'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:103:in `parse'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/parser.rb:66:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:180:in `parse_response'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:164:in `handle_response'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty/request.rb:57:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty.rb:280:in `perform_request'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.6.1/lib/httparty.rb:232:in `get'
        from twitter_friends_2.rb:11:in `get_username_data'
        from twitter_friends_2.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you try user_id instead of screen_name?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Crack. I've come across it on occasion while using the gem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your method with this

```
def self.get_username_data(username)
  get("/statuses/friends.json?screen_name=#{username}")
end
```

OR

```
def self.get_username_data(username)
  get('/statuses/friends.json' , :query => { :screen_name => username.strip })
end
```

You need to strip the username because from command line when user enters the twitter username and hits enter key a "\n" gets appended to the username and the same username is sent as a parameter which causes the problem. Any of the above given code snippets should work.